# How does enthalpy of a reaction vary with pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

Kirchhoff's law gives us a way to find variation in enthalpy of a reaction with temperature
But is there some equivalent law for pressures?
Ie, given a reaction and it's enthalpy at a pressure P1, is it possible to calculate it's enthalpy at a pressure P2

Comment: These can be applied the Hess law for p shift instead of usual T shift.

Comment: Do you know how to find the effect of pressure on enthalpy for a pure species?

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if there was a formula analogous to kirchoffs law

Comment: I guess writing down the enthalpy pressure corrections for reactants and products and combining them appropriately would be equivalent.  this would also take into account non-ideal effects.